# Can I take the natural logarithm of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, logarithms

Can I say

$$\ln \left( \{1,e,e^2\} \right) = \{0,1,2\}$$

Is this correct use of set notation?

Comment: If you're dealing with Numpy or Mathematica or any other programming language, yes. If dealing with real mathematics... you have to define how a function applies over a set.

Comment: I'm just asking in general, as in would it be appropriate to write something like this? Or even $2 \cdot \{1,2\}=\{2,4\}$?

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ denotes a function and $A\subseteq X$ then  the set $\{f(x)\mid x\in A\}$ is often denoted as $f(A)$. This is what happens here.

Comment: If you use the standard definition $f(X)=\{f(x)\,:\, x\in X\}$, then yes. Though what you wrote is not exactly something you often see written.

Comment: This is standard notation: Given a function $f: X \to Y$ and a subset $A \subseteq X$, $f(A)$ denotes the set $\{f(a) : a \in A\}$. A bit more formally one might describe the set as "the image of the given set under the natural logarithm" rather than "the natural logarithm of the given set".

Comment: I see. Thank you everyone for the answers!